How can I retrieve all hierarchical user data from MySQL tables?
This is a simplified version of my MySql tables.
User table



user_id
user_name
manager_user_id




1
John
Null


2
Maria
1


3
Rob
2


4
Alex
3



User Data table



id
user_id
some_user_data




1
2
abc


2
3
def


3
4
ghi


4
2
jkl



Here, John is the manager of Maria, Maria is the manager of Rob, and Rob is the manager of Alex. Based on this hierarchy:
• John can see the data for Maria, Rob, and Alex
• Maria can see the data for Rob and Alex
• Rob can see the data for Alex from the User Data Table
Help me to write a query that will satisfy the above condition and works for large datasets.

Recursive CTEs are what you're probably looking for.

SELECT * FROM User Data table a
INNER JOIN (
SELECT 
@mid as ids,
(SELECT @mid := GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) FROM User table WHERE find_in_set(manager_user_id,@mid)) t
FROM User table,(SELECT @mid := 1) tmp) b FIND_IN_SET(a.user_id,b.ids)

